# How do I make a simple jQuery plugin that's not bound to an element?

Tags: jquery, plugins

For some reason I can only find plugin examples that are directly bound to an existing element like $(selector).myPlugin();

What I want to be able to do is quite simply just call new myPlugin() with options.

```
new myPlugin({
    'option1': 'option 1 value',
    'option2': 'option 2 value',
    'option3': 'option 3 value',
    'option4': 'option 4 value'
});
```

I have a regular function that has up to 8 parameters, but I don't always need to define them all and I hate having to include the defaults for all of the parameters I don't need to define.

```
function myFunction(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8){
    // Operations here
}
```

Sometimes I only need to define the first and fifth parameters or whatever and I need defaults for the rest. This is a pain.

Maybe I've missed an example like this here in my searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the `$` namespace to declare your new function and use `$.extend()` to handle your defaults:

```
(function($) {
    var defaults = {
       name: 'Jack',
       number: '555-jack'
    }

    $.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.someFunction = function() {
            // you can use settings here
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I'm defining the defaults as a private variable (outside code can't access it) and use it inside the `myPlugin` constructor. An example how the call works:

```
var x = new $.myPlugin({
    number: '666-something'
});
```

Inside the constructor, the `settings` variable contains the name from `defaults` and the number from the constructor arguments.

Comment: Ok, that looks promising. Can I add methods to the plugin, like x.someFunction(); or does that completely change how the plugin is built?

Comment: I'm guessing the $. is because we're building right off the jQuery object instead of $(selector)? Thanks for the quick answer on this. Works great and is simple.

Comment: I'm using `$.extend()`; you can do this whole construct without passing jQuery around, but you will have to find a way to do object cloning yourself :)

Comment: Ha, maybe I should ask separately about events? Or is that also easy to add to this? Let's say I just want to add an onShow event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11995/discussion-between-tomas-and-jack)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arrays or JSON as a single parameter to your function instead of individual values.